# Zend - Design Pattern DataMapper & Table Gateway

Tags: zend-framework, design-patterns

This is directly out of the Zend Quick Start guide. My question is: why would you need the `setDbTable()` method when the `getDbTable()` method assigns a default `Zend_Db_Table` object? If you know this mapper uses a particular table, why even offer the possibility of potentially using the "wrong" table via `setDbTable()`? What flexibility do you gain by being able to set the table if the rest of the code (`find()`, `fetchAll()` etc.) is specific to `Guestbook`?

```
class Application_Model_GuestbookMapper 
{
    protected $_dbTable; 

    public function setDbTable($dbTable)
    {
        if (is_string($dbTable)) { 
            $dbTable = new $dbTable();
        }
        if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided'); 
        }
        $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDbTable() 
    {
        if (null === $this->_dbTable) { 
            $this->setDbTable('Application_Model_DbTable_Guestbook');
        }
        return $this->_dbTable;
    }

    ... GUESTBOOK SPECIFIC CODE ...
}

class Application_Model_DbTable_Guestbook extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'guestbook_table';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phil is correct, this is known as [lazy-loading design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading). I just implemented this pattern in a recent project, because of these benefits:

- When I call on getMember() method, I will get a return value, regardless if it has been set before or not. This is great for [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining): `$this->getCar()->getTires()->getSize();`
- This pattern offers flexibility in that outside calling code is still able to set member values: `$myClass->setCar(new Car());`

-- EDIT --

Use caution when implementing the lazy-loading design pattern. If your objects are not properly hydrated, a query will be issued for every piece of data which is NOT available. The best thing to do is tail your db query log, during the dev phase, to ensure the number and type of queries are what you expect. A project I was working on was issuing over 27 queries for a "detail" page, and I had no idea until I saw the queries.

Answer (score 1):

This method is called lazy-loading. It allows a property to remain null until requested unless it is set earlier.

One use for `setDbTable()` would be testing. This way you could set a mock DB table or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

One addition: if `setDbTable()` is solely for lazy-loading, wouldn't it make more sense to make it private? That way it will avoid accidental assignment and to wrong table as originally mentioned by Sam.
Should we be compromising the design for the sake of testability?